# SDL 2 Space keydown not detected but Space keyup works fine

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Hey so I'm working on a project/2d game and I'm having some odd behavior from SDL which I'm sure is probably something I'm not understanding. The function ProcessKeys is called and works fine for all the key press downs except SDLK_SPACE and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

What is even more bizarre is that the SDL_KEYUP switch of SDLK_SPACE works great. I tried using some debugging code to print out which key is being pressed and when you press space down nothing registers. Every other key on the keyboard registers in my debug statement at the top of the SDL_KEYDOWN case.

If anyone can see what is going on I would really appreciate it.

And if you need to see where its being called let me know.

```
SDLKeyboard::KeyState SDLKeyboard::ProcessKeys(SDL_Event * event)
{
switch(event->type)
{
    /* Look for a keypress */
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
    {
        std::cout << "Key currently pressed" << event->key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        /* Check the SDLKey values and move change the coords */
            switch(event->key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                {    // rotate the ship left
                    c.setIsTurningLeft(true);
                    return this->keystate = LeftPressed;
                    // add code when user presses left
                    break;
                }
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                {
                // rotate the ship right
                    c.setIsTurningRight(true);
                    return this->keystate = RightPressed;
                    // add code when user presses right
                    break;
                }
                case SDLK_UP:
                {    
                    // accleration
                    c.setIsAccelerating(true);
                    return this->keystate = UpPressed;
                    // add code when user presses up
                    break;
                }
                case SDLK_SPACE:
                {    
                    // shoot
                    c.setIsShooting(true);
                    std::cout << "keystate = " << this->keystate;
                    return this->keystate = SpacePressed;
                    // add code when user presses space
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    return this->keystate = NotPressed;
                    break;
                }
            }
        break;
    }
    /* We must also use the SDL_KEYUP events to zero the x */
    /* and y velocity variables. But we must also be       */
    /* careful not to zero the velocities when we shouldn't*/
    case SDL_KEYUP:
    {   
        std::cout << "Key currently pressed" << event->key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
        switch(event->key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_LEFT:
             {   /* We check to make sure the ship is moving */
                /* to the left. If it is then we zero the    */
                /* velocity. If the ship is moving to the   */
                /* right then the right key is still press   */
                /* so we don't touch the velocity            */
                c.setIsTurningLeft(false);
                return this->keystate = LeftReleased;
                // code to do things when left isn't pushed anymore but still moving left
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            {    // code to do things when right isn't pushed anymore but still moving right
                c.setIsTurningRight(false);
                return this->keystate = RightReleased;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_UP:
            {    // code to do things when up isn't pushed anymore but still moving up
                c.setIsAccelerating(false);
                return this->keystate = UpReleased;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_SPACE:
            {    // accleration
                c.setIsShooting(false);
                return this->keystate = SpaceReleased;
                // add code when user presses up
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        return this->keystate = NotPressed;
        break;
    }
 }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the example requested. The other thing that I've noticed is the latency in response isn't that great. Like if you press a key sometimes the console doesn't print the corresponding key. Probably has to do with the issue I'm having with the space as well.

```
void GUI::TakeInput(SDL_Event *e)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(e))
        OnEvent(e);
}
void SDLEvent::OnEvent(SDL_Event * event) 
{
    switch(event->type) 
    {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN: 
        {
            OnKeyDown(event->key.keysym.sym);
            break;
        }

        case SDL_KEYUP:
        {
            OnKeyUp(event->key.keysym.sym);
            break;
        }

        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
        {
            OnMouseMove(event->motion.x,event->motion.y);
            break;
        }

        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
        {
            OnMouseButtonDown(event->button.button, event->button.x,event->button.y);
            break;
        }

        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        {
            OnMouseButtonUp(event->button.button, event->button.x,event->button.y);
            break;
        }

        case SDL_QUIT: {
            OnExit();
            break;
        }

        case SDL_SYSWMEVENT: {
            //Ignore
            break;
        }

        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED: {
            OnResize();
            break;
        }

        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED: {
            OnExpose();
            break;
        }

        default: {
            OnUser(event->user.type,event->user.code,event->user.data1,event->user.data2);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void GUI::Play()
{
    Uint32 start_ticks = SDL_GetTicks();
    TakeInput(this->setup->GetEvent());
    this->keyboard->ProcessKeys(this->setup->GetEvent());
    this->setup->RenderBegin();
    this->ship->drawBackBuffer();
    this->ship->renderSprite();
    Uint32 end_ticks = SDL_GetTicks();
    int sleep_delay = (1000 / 60) - (end_ticks-start_ticks);

     if (sleep_delay > 0) {
      SDL_Delay(sleep_delay);
     }     
}
```

Comment: Where do you call sdl poll event?

Comment: Right before I call this function there is a while loop with SDL_PollEvent.

Comment: That is not very helpful. Producing a minimal test example would be great.

Comment: Sorry you weren't very specific. I hope the added code adds enough to give you an idea of how its working. I recently tried changing to SDL_Scancode and it seems to work better than the event based keydown but my issue then becomes latency.

Comment: how do you detect, that it's not working?  you std::cout the old state?  so your only indicator would be that your ``c`` is not accelerating.  is this function working properly, if e.g. placed on another key?

Comment: my std::cout << event->key.keysym.sym should print out whatever key is being pressed at the current time if I understand that correctly. It never prints anything when I press the spacebar. It gives a cout for any other key but only the space it doesn't. I have been able to get a respond from the spacebar by using key.keysym.scancode which is bizarre. Also the project is with multiple other people and the other guys method  c.isNotAccelerating(bool) isn't testable at the current time which is why I'm trying to determine if mine works independently first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only writing `event->key.keysym.sym` on the console, you should know that the spacebar key produces an almost invisible character.

Try this instead:

```cpp
std::cout << "<" << event->key.keysym.sym << ">"
```

So you can see whataver invisible character printed between angle brackets.